# How to return 204 for Null list or objective instead of 200 []

Tags: java, spring, rest

My question what can i do in order to get 204 no content for empty list or null objective?
https://github.com/aykut16/prott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ResponseEntity model please see the following example:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getall")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findAll() {
  List<User> users = repository.findAll();
  if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users)){
    return ResponseEntity.noContent()
        .build();
  }
  return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .body(users);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much

Comment: ops! i forgot that.